# Default values for missing fields in a left join?

Tags: join, apache-pig

In Pig, when I do left join and a row does not have row, the values are `NULL`:

```
c = join a by ($0) left, b by ($0);
```

if

```
a=((1,10),(2,20))
b=((1,30))
```

then

```
c=((1,10,30),(2,20,NULL))
```

I want to use a default value (say, `-1`) instead of `NULL` so that

```
c=((1,10,30),(2,20,-1))
```

How do I do that?

If that is impossible, how do I change the 3rd column of `c` to have the default value instead of `NULL`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware if that can be done within the join statement, but you add add another statement:

```
d = FOREACH c GENERATE $0, $1, (($2 IS NULL) ? -1 : $2);
```

I guess it won't trigger an additional MR job.

Comment: Does '-1' have to be quoted?

Comment: If you treat it as integers then no, sorry. I've updated the answer.